# MLKit face detection gives Invalid image data size for image

Tags: android, android-camera, face-detection, firebase-mlkit

Hi I am using firebase MLKit and camera 1 resources. I am facing issue while processing image data captured from camera. My code looks like :

```
@Override
public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {

  FirebaseVisionFaceDetectorOptions options = new FirebaseVisionFaceDetectorOptions.Builder()
          .setPerformanceMode(FirebaseVisionFaceDetectorOptions.FAST)
          .setLandmarkMode(FirebaseVisionFaceDetectorOptions.ALL_LANDMARKS)
          .build();

  FirebaseVisionFaceDetector detector = FirebaseVision.getInstance().getVisionFaceDetector(options);
  int height = camera.getParameters().getPreviewSize().height;
  int width = camera.getParameters().getPreviewSize().width;
  FirebaseVisionImageMetadata metadata = new FirebaseVisionImageMetadata.Builder()
          .setFormat(FirebaseVisionImageMetadata.IMAGE_FORMAT_NV21)
          .setWidth(width)
          .setHeight(height)
          .setRotation(3)
          .build();

  FirebaseVisionImage firebaseVisionImage = FirebaseVisionImage.fromByteArray(data, metadata);

  detector.detectInImage(firebaseVisionImage).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<List<FirebaseVisionFace>>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(List<FirebaseVisionFace> firebaseVisionFaces) {
    }
  }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
    }
  });
}
```

I am getting following fatal exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid image data size.
        at com.google.android.gms.vision.Frame$Builder.setImageData(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.firebase.ml.vision.common.FirebaseVisionImage.zzb(com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision@@22.0.0:145)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_ml.zzqp.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision@@22.0.0:11)
        at com.google.firebase.ml.vision.face.FirebaseVisionFaceDetector.detectInImage(com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision@@22.0.0:25)
```

Above issue occurring only on certain device.For few devices it is working fine but for some device it is giving above error. Also if I create bitmap from same byte array and pass it to FirebaseVisionFaceDetector it works fine. But issue is it makes process slower.

Comment: Try checking if Camera.getParameters().getPreviewFormat() is correct. Also it's unclear to me if you really want getPreviewSize instead of getPictureSize. Maybe they are the same on some devices. Just a guess.

Comment: I have checked preview format for camera. Its same as that of which I am setting it for FirebaseVisionImageMetadata